# Java - Taking user input to access an array then print information

Tags: java

I am making a program that ask the user to type in a car model example Honda, and access the Honda class.  After the user types in the model he is asked to choose a Honda model example "Civic".  When he types "Civic" the different years come up 2000,2013 etc.. He chooses a year than information about that car comes up.

I already have the first part asking the user to type in the car model and accessing the class. I am not planing on adding much information this is just a project i'm working on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class carMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Honda hondaMain = new Honda("civic");

        System.out.println("Welcome to GoAuto.  Search from thousands of cars. \n");
        System.out.println("Please enter the brand of car you would like to search:");
        String carBrand = input.nextLine();

        if (carBrand.equalsIgnoreCase("Honda") == true) {

            System.out.println("You are now in the Honda class");
            //model type
            String carBrand1 = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming I would need to create an array to store the information about the car models and the year but i'm not sure how to do this.

```
public class Honda {
    String c;
    Honda(String civi) {
        c = civi;
    }

    void simplemsg() {
        System.out.println("You are now in Honda Database");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to store the information in some kind of Database? that will make it easy for you to access and display the data to the user

Comment: I ask this question because of the issue of scope: is this for a homework assignment or for something for production?  Because the data structure is pretty large, and I would not use arrays, as it would become unmaintainable. As @LearningPhase just noted, a database is part of the solution to this question for anything real.

Comment: Off topic but `if(boolean == true)` is unnecessary. You can simply write `if(boolean)`.

Comment: It's just for a small project. I wanted to get used to using classes and accessing information.  I'm not planning on adding much.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I think you would want to create classes that represent each level. For instance..

```
public class Make(){
    //Add class properties
    List<Models> models = new ArrayList();


    public function Model get_model_by_name(String name) {
        //int index = search for matching Model.name..
        return this.models(index)
}

public class Model(){
    //Add class properties
    List<Years> years = new ArrayList();


    public function Model get_year_by_name(String name) {
        //int index = search for matching Year.name..
        return this.models(index)
}

public class Year(){
    //Add class properties
    String info;
    String info2;
}
```

Then in the main method, you would want to initialize the values like so..

```
//Initialize database
List<Make> database = new arrayList();
Make ford = new Make(<insert values for all properties>)
database.add(ford);

// Access ford..
System.out.println(ford.get_year_by_name(<whatever value user passed in>)
```

Obviously this is pseudo-code and you would need to add whatever constructors and properties you want as well as the appropriate getters and setters. The ideal situation would to use a database lookup or an enumeration file of some sort.

Comment: Weird Java syntax ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put == true after your equalsIgnoreCase

```
if(carBrand.equalsIgnoreCase("Honda")){
```

If you wanted to store both year and car info in an array, look into two dimensional arrays. As the other answers says though you could look into some more cohesive ways to code this